# Partial view not found exception with asp.net core in IIS only

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, partial-views

We are having problems with partial views after migrating to .net 5. The main page will optionally render a custom partial view to allow per-customer customizations. After migrating we are unable to render these partial views. the error message is:

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view ~/Resources/Customer/Views/File.cshtml was not found. The following locations were searched: ~/Resources/Customer/Views/File.cshtml
```

We know the path is valid because if we rename the file the page renders (without customizations). If we debug in visual studio the page renders as expected but in a deployed IIS server it fails. We suspect there is a permissions issue but we have been unable to find it. So far we haven't been able to find anything in google searches or SO

Here is a snippet where we handle the custom file:

```
// load file path from config
string url = configuration.OrderPageSetting["OrderInfoViewRenderFile"];
bool exists = false;

// determine the path
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
{
    string _url = url;
    if (_url.StartsWith("~/")) _url = _url.Substring(2);
    else if (_url.StartsWith("/")) _url = _url.Substring(1);
    exists = System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(Resource.SystemDirectory, _url));
}

// test for and render custom view
if (exists)
{
    var data = new ViewDataDictionary<object>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary());
    data.Add("Order", order);
    data.Add("Config", configuration);
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync(url, data);
}
else
{
... default rendering ...
}
```

The application is hosted in a virtual directory with a dedicated application pool. This problem occurs without a web.config at the site level. On the same server, the prior .net framework version of the application works correctly.

here is the applications web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please share the IIS site's folder? Do you host your application as a specific web application or  a nested web sites or virtual directory ?

Comment: It is hosted as a web application under a virtual directory with a dedicated applicaiton pool. the Site folder does not have a web.config currently defined (i tried removing it just in case). I will put a copy of apps web.config in the original post.

Comment: Could you please share the IIS management console for this site? It seems you put this application inside a virtual directory, I suggest you could try to put this site inside a specific web application inside IIS and try again.

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker found the solution the problem, the clue was in https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Sep/30/Serving-ASPNET-Core-Web-Content-from-External-Folders

There were 2 changes required:

1. Add package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
2. called extension to support runtime complication on the controllers/views:

```
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(opt =>
    {
        opt.FileProviders.Add(
            new PhysicalFileProvider(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, ""))
        );
    })
```

if you want to change where the dynamic compilation is supported, simply change the "" to the path where it is permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project page (ProjectName.csproj) and check the following line is there  or not
 `<Content Remove="Views\**\**.cshtml" />`

if there , please remove. And include the following

`<None Include="Views\**\**.cshtml" />`

Note:-Please replace the url with your partial page url.